# How to Make Gridview Column Selection in a Loop using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please i have the below code that upon button click event, i create a delimited string from a gridview and display it  in a textbox. Currently the loop creates the delimited string using all the columns available in the gridview. How do i specify only the columns that is needed to create the delimited string.
Per the image below i don't want the storeid column to be part of the delimeted string
[image]

This code is what am using to create the delimeted string

```
protected void CreatePOEntryString2()
    {
        {
            string MyResults = "";

            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in griditem.Rows)
            {
                if (MyResults != "")
                    MyResults += "|";
                string MyRow = "";

                foreach (TableCell tCell in gRow.Cells)
                {
                    if (MyRow != "")
                        MyRow += ",";
                    MyRow += tCell.Text;
                }
                MyResults += MyResults;
            }
            txtPODetails.Text = MyResults + ItemPipe;
        }
    }
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

you can simply filter out `storeid` from the inner foreach (if you want to go with this approach)

```
foreach (TableCell tCell in gRow.Cells.where (x=>x.Text!="storeid"))
        {
            if (MyRow != "")
                MyRow += ",";
            MyRow += tCell.Text;
        }
```